# Setting up listener using IBM MQ in eclipse using wlp for java springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq, websphere-liberty, spring-jms, server.xml

Setting up listener using IBM MQ in eclipse using wlp for java springboot application

Hi, I am trying to set up listener using wlp in my local in eclipse,
following is the code :

pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

java class:

```
@JmsListener(containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory", destination = test.queue)
public void recieve(Message message)  {
    log.info("inside message receiver");
    try {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            message.acknowledge();
            String json = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
            /** To solve Json injection fortify issue **/
            String sanitisedJsonMessage = JsonSanitizer.sanitize(json);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
           //business logic
        } else {
            log.error("ERROR ::: invalid message type");
            message.acknowledge();
        }
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException | JMSException  ex) {
        log.error("ERROR: " + ex + ex.getMessage());

    }
}


@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConnectionFactory connectionfactory;
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory listenerFactory;
    try {
        log.info("inside listener factory");
        @Cleanup
        Context context = null;
        listenerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        context = new InitialContext();
        connectionfactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup(jms/ConnectionFactory);
        listenerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionfactory);
        listenerFactory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        log.error("ERROR: error looking up queue connection factory jndi {}", ex);
    }
    return listenerFactory;
}
```

Now I tried to set up my server.xml in wlp as per ibm guidelines as follows:

```
<server description="new server">
    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>
        <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
        <feature>mdb-3.2</feature>
        <feature>wmqJmsClient-2.0</feature>
        <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <!-- Define an Administrator and non-Administrator -->
    <basicRegistry id="basic">
        <user name="admin" password="adminpwd" />
        <user name="nonadmin" password="nonadminpwd" />
    </basicRegistry>

    <!-- Assign 'admin' to Administrator -->
    <administrator-role>
        <user>admin</user>
    </administrator-role>
    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="Liberty" />


    <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="9081" httpsPort="9444"
        id="defaultHttpEndpoint" />



    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true" />
    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />

    <enterpriseApplication
        id="mqtest-ear"
        location="mqtest-ear.ear"
        name="mqtest-ear" />


    <variable name="wmqJmsClient.rar.location"
        value="path\to\wlp\wmq\wmq.jmsra.rar" />

    <jmsQueueConnectionFactory
        jndiName="jms/ConnectionFactory">
        <properties.wmqJms transportType="CLIENT"
            hostName="<test.correcthostname>" port="<test.correctportname>"
            channel="<test.correctchannelname>" queueManager="<test.correctqmgrname>" useSSL="true"
            headerCompression="SYSTEM" messageCompression="RLE"
            sslCipherSuite="SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"
            targetClientMatching="true" />
        <connectionManager></connectionManager>
    </jmsQueueConnectionFactory>


    <jmsQueue id="JMSQueue" jndiName="jms/InQueue">
        <properties.wmqJms baseQueueName="test.queue"
            baseQueueManagerName="<test.correctqmgrname>" receiveConversion="CLIENT_MSG"
            putAsyncAllowed="DESTINATION" targetClient="MQ"
            readAheadAllowed="ENABLED" />
    </jmsQueue>


<!--    <resourceAdapter
        location="${wmqJmsClient.rar.location}" id="resourceAdapter">
    </resourceAdapter> -->

    <keyStore id="keyAndTrustStore" password="password"
        location="path\to\keyandtruststore"
        type="PKCS12">
    </keyStore>
```

I have downloaded latest resource adapter and 9.0.0.8-IBM-MQ-Java-InstallRA.jar,
When I run the application , I get constant error:

```
2020-01-10 11:21:16 ERROR o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'test.queue' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=12, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection.
```

what Can I do to make listener work

Comment: Should `destination = test.queue` be `destination = jms/InQueue`?

Comment: no, It should be a queuename and not a jndi name according to jms specifications

Comment: What version of liberty are you using?

Comment: @JoshMc  liberty version-17.0.0.4

Answer (score 0):

After trying and troubleshoting a lot, I found a solution to set up ibm mq message listener using springboot and jms locally in websphere liberty server version 19.0.0.6.
I used following steps to make listener work:

1. download resource adaptor 9.0.0.8-IBM-MQ-Java-InstallRA.jar
2. Run the jar, and a folder named wmq will be generated with required .rar file in it.
3. Place the wmq folder inside wlp server : path\to\wlp-webProfile8-19.0.0.6\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer
4. if using keystores for ssl , place trust and key store .jks or .p12 file inside wlp server       path\to\wlp-webProfile8-19.0.0.6\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer\resources\security
5. create a new file name jvm.options with following details:

   ```
   -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false
   -Djavax.net.debug="all"
   -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.2"
   -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.2"
   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="path\to\keyandtruststore.jks"
   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="secret"
   -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="path\to\keyandtruststore.jks"
   -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="secret"
   ```
6. save file inside following location : path\to\wlp-webProfile8-19.0.0.6\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer
7. now add required dependencies in pom.xml
   I am using spring boot version 2.1.4.release and following are important dependecies which will be required:

   ```
   <dependency>
           <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
           <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
           <version>2.1.2</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
           <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
8. now change the wlp server.xml as follows:

   ```
   <!-- Enable features -->
   <featureManager>
       <feature>webProfile-8.0</feature>
       <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
       <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
       <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>
       <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>
       <feature>wmqJmsClient-2.0</feature>
       <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
       <feature>servlet-4.0</feature>
       <feature>jms-2.0</feature>
       <feature>javaee-8.0</feature>
   </featureManager>

   <!-- Define an Administrator and non-Administrator -->
   <basicRegistry id="basic">
       <user name="admin" password="adminpwd"/>
       <user name="nonadmin" password="nonadminpwd"/>
   </basicRegistry>
   <!-- Assign 'admin' to Administrator -->
   <administrator-role>
       <user>admin</user>
   </administrator-role>

   <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
   <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
   <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>

   <variable name="wmqJmsClient.rar.location" value="path\to\wlp-webProfile8-19.0.0.6\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer\wmq\wmq.jmsra.rar"/>

   <jmsQueueConnectionFactory jndiName="jms/ConnectionFactory" id="QueueConnectionFactory ">
       <properties.wmqJms channel="channelName" headerCompression="NONE" hostName="host name" messageCompression="RLE" port="1414" queueManager="qmgrName" sslCipherSuite="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256" targetClientMatching="true" transportType="CLIENT" temporaryModel="SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE" pollingInterval="5s" rescanInterval="5s"/>
       <connectionManager connectionTimeout="180s" maxPoolSize="20" minPoolSize="1" reapTime="180s" agedTimeout="0" maxIdleTime="30m"/>
   </jmsQueueConnectionFactory>


   <jmsQueue id="JMSQueue" jndiName="jms/testInQueue">
       <properties.wmqJms putAsyncAllowed="DISABLED" readAheadAllowed="ENABLED" receiveConversion="CLIENT_MSG" targetClient="JMS" baseQueueName="queueName" baseQueueManagerName="qmgrName" failIfQuiesce="true" persistence="APP"/>
   </jmsQueue>


   <!-- <wmqJmsClient nativeLibraryPath="C:\Users\n78724\CRAS\resource adapter\lib"/> -->

   <resourceAdapter id="resourceAdapter"
       location="${wmqJmsClient.rar.location}">
       <customize></customize>
   </resourceAdapter>

   <ssl id="keyAndTrustStore" keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" trustStoreRef="defaultTrustStore"/>
   <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" location="path\to\wlp-webProfile8-19.0.0.6\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer\resources\security\keyandtruststore.jks" password="secret"/>
   <keyStore id="defaultTrustStore" location="path\to\wlp-webProfile8-19.0.0.6\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer\resources\security\keyandtruststore.jks" password="secret"/>


   <enterpriseApplication id="Test-ear" location="Test-ear.ear" name="Test-ear"/>
   ```
9. start the server

hope it helps.